# For cycle does not replace first symbol in a given range

Tags: python

I tried to run a code in python to remove symbols with index 0, 3, 6, 9... etc.  I decided to choose "for" cycle for it. Question: Why does the code not replacing the first symbol?

```
>>> s = 'Python'
>>> a = len(s)
>>> a
6
>>> for i in range (0, a, 3):
    b = s.replace(s[i], '')


>>> b
'Pyton'
>>>
```

Comment: `b = s` `for i in range (0, a, 3): b = b.replace(b[i], '')`

Comment: It does replace the first symbol, but you keep overwriting `b`, so only the last change is left in it. (There are other problems with it, this is the immediate one. For example, even when this is corrected, your code will not do the right thing on `"ooooooooh no"`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you edit your code to print the variables after every loop, you'll figure out what's happening:

```
s = 'Python'
a = len(s)
for i in range (0, a, 3):
    b = s.replace(s[i], '')
    print(i, s, b)
print(">", b)
```

prints out

```
0 Python ython
3 Python Pyton
> Pyton
```

This is because you're assigning to `b`, but using `s` as the source replacement string.

You'll get closer by reassigning to `s` instead:

```py
s = 'Python'
a = len(s)
for i in range (0, a, 3):
    s = s.replace(s[i], '')
    print(i, s)
print(">", s)
```

```
0 ython
3 ythn
> ythn
```

However note that since you're shortening the string in-place, the indices have changed, and you're not replacing the characters you think you might be. More so if there are multiple instances of the same character, as `replace` will remove them all.

Answer (score 2):

You are overriding `b` on each iteration. A one liner solution that helps avoiding these mistakes could be:

```py
b = "".join([l for i, l in enumerate(s) if i % 3 != 0])
```

Example:

```py
In [6]: s = "Python"
In [7]: b = "".join([l for i, l in enumerate(s) if i % 3 != 0])                                                                                                                                                       
In [8]: b                                                                                                                                                                                                             
Out[8]: 'yton'
```

Answer (score 0):

In each cycle you are overriding the last `b`.
put a `print` function inside your loop you will understand.

first you will get `ython` and the second cycle you will get `Pyton`.